# Non repeated Generation of Asymetric Keys

Tags: algorithm, security, cryptography, rsa

How do you know that the same key pair hasn't been generated ever before?

I guess the system you will access with your keys will keep track of keys that have already been generated and are being used therefore if the algorithm generates a repeated one, it will discard it.

If that's the case there exists the risk of someone flooding a system with "easily" generated keys until you find one it's already there and steal the identity.

I deduce I'm wrong since things seem to work correctly in the world so far, so why? How do you know if your key pair generator hasn't created an already used key?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not directly related to development, try [security.se] but search for earlier Q/A's first.

Comment: You generate a key randomly out of a space of keys so large such that it is unlikely it has ever been used by anyone, ever.  Then don't worry about collisions.